# CSS Help: text positioning over image

Tags: html, css, positioning

Say I have an image that is 1000x1000. On top of the image, I want to place, say, the letter "A". Here are the details:

- Bottom value is 160 (meaning, the bottommost part of the "A" is sitting 160px from the top of the image)
- Left value is also 160 (meaning, the leftmost part of the "A" is sitting 160px from the left of the image)

I need this positioning to be relative. Say the image is reduced to 50% its original size, then the bottom and left values should become 80 and 80. (By the way, I picked 160px as an example so conversion to `em` would be easy.)

The image probably needs to be in its own container as it needs to be positioned on the page, as well. But right now, I just need help with positioning letters on an image. Any guidance you can offer is appreciated.

Comment: Is this a background image in css? Padding should position the text properly with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a div with background image and text inside it. position the text.

i.e

```
<div id="imageHolder"><span class="imageText"> some text</span> </div>

#imageholder {
width: 1000px;
height: 1000px;
background: transparent url(path/to/your.img) 0 0 no-repeat;
position: relative;
}
.imageText {
position: absolute;
top: 160px;
left: 160px;
 }
```

you can use percentages for top and left values when scaling. or fiddle with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/Gg29e/1/

Comment: @Sebastian: I modified your solution so that it's inline CSS. See: http://jsfiddle.net/Gg29e/3/. Must I use percentage so that the text will be relative to the image? Will em work? Are there going to be any problems with this solution?

Comment: @Sebastian: also, the user viewing this image with overlaid text will be resizing the image (e.g. like a zoom function). How would I set this up such that I would need to modify the least amount of inline CSS for things to still align properly?

Comment: a difficult problem without more details.  who are you target browsers/devices? is ie6 important? is it absolutely necessary to use inline styles? could you modify the values of the css classes dynamically? can you use the css zoom property? without very specific answers to those problems, it's hard to answer a question like 'will there be problems'? i suggest trial an error with the methods oulined in these answers, ad then re-post very specific questions.

Comment: @Sebastian, I need to do this for a lot of images, each being viewed concurrently by different users. I *think* inline CSS might be the best approach. What do I need to do to the containing div so that the plotted text is relative to this container?

Comment: hey again, i checked out what you are trying to do.  a PDF viewer, right?  IMHO, you need to hire a top-notch HTML/CSS guy to help you with this.  you are dealing with a very complex problem, and Stack Overflow will provide you with specific answers to specific questions, but you are dealing with very general and complex questions.

Comment: that being said, i see that google pdf reader puts each line of highlighted text and positions it relative to its parent div (the image).  I think you are on the right path. if you use porition relative for the image container and position: absolute for the spans of characters or divs of text, you should be able to place them above the document image.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, just use a background image and some padding:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xzbcy/

Try this combined effort from me and Seb:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gg29e/4/

Comment: @Grillz, I don't see how you are plotting the text. Also, can you show how to do this using inline CSS? I need to dynamically generate the mark up and CSS for this problem.

Comment: @Newbie the padding places the text. in your example, it would be: padding-left: 160px; padding-top: 160px;

Comment: btw, Grillz's solution is the most elegant if you only need to place one text item on the image.

Comment: @Sebastia, I do need to place a LOT of text on top of the image. So, I think Grillz's approach is not suitable for my problem?

Comment: do you mean: ) a lot of text in one paragraph, or b)lots of different text items? if a, then grillz approach still best, if b) then i sggest you used the approach i oulined in my solution, giving each span of text an id and positioning them.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to add paragraph tags etc. It's going to be hard to say without seeing more of what you plan to do.

Comment: @Grillz, I'm basically trying to allow users to select text on top of an image. Something like GMail's PDF viewer. I know where the text is supposed to be (as I have the coordinates of each letter).

Comment: @Sebastian: it's option B. I think I need to use in-line CSS as I do need to generate the mark up/styles dynamically. And remember, size of the image will change (e.g. via zoom in or zoom out); I need the text to stay in the proper place.

Comment: This may be going over my head than, and perhaps Sebastian can be of more help. If you are working with his JSfiddle just use p tags instead of span tags. Finally, perhaps wrap all of the text with another div that has your inline styles and a width to dynamically change the size with your image.

Comment: @Newbie See my edit please. Is that more what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If the image is not a bg img, you can try something like this (I have not tested it though)

- Enclose the image in a div
- Make height and width of the div auto so it gets the height and width of the image
- Place your text in a span and give it a higher z-index than your image (say z-index 2 for the span and 1 for the image)
- You can then place your span relative to the div and it should appear on top of your image.